# How to add a tester to specific build on testFlight That already upload before adding the tester

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I need to add tester to old build that already submitted so I can check if there will be any issues with updating process

**what I've tried**

> 1. create a Testers Groupe on App Store Connects
> 2. add That specific tester to that Group
> 3. add the build to that group

The problem is that it shows me status **`No Builds Available`** as the next screenshots
[image]

> The Question is How can I solve this issue and if I can't add an old build to a new tester then is there's a way to check updating app before submitting the new build to the app store review.

Comment: Have you submitted that version for TestFlight review?  You can't provide un-reviewed builds to external testers

Comment: Yes I have submitted before for testFlight.

Comment: If that version has any builds reviewed then it should be available to even newly added testers.

Comment: The latest build is the one that is available i need to add an old build not the latest. Do you think it’s possible?

Comment: You just add the user to the latest version and they can see earlier versions in the TestFlight app under “previous builds”